# Jmeter: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)

Tags: jmeter, connection

I am  getting the below exception (java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl) in Jmeter, I am manually able access the application so there is no problem from the server.I suspect it is related to the Port. Before this i have opened around more than 15 instances of jmeter to create test data, Is that might have caused this problem?

What is the clear difference in terms of network between making the request through jemeter and manual request?.Please let me know if any other additional information is required?

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
>       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:542)
>       at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:414)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.LazySchemeSocketFactory.connectSocket(LazySchemeSocketFactory.java:97)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.hc.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:318)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.open(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:114)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:654)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:413)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1189)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1178)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:491)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:425)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:254)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Are you getting this error in a Windows Machine?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. It does not occur for all the requests I send. I'm using a Windows Machine. Can anyone please help?